# Return Dialog Result in custom Messagebox

Tags: c#, winforms

I am trying to make a custom MessageBox. I am calling a simple form with a private constructor and a static "show" method. It will have a OK and possibly a cancel button dynamically created, depending on what the user passes in. I create the Click event handler when i create the button. 
What I'd like to know is how to pass the DialogResult back to the caller.
Here is the code to create the button (show) and the event handler.

```
public static DialogResult Show(string title, string message, ButtonStyle buttonStyle) {
    AFGMessageBox box = new AFGMessageBox();
    box.Text = title;
    box.LblMessage.Text = message;
    if (buttonStyle == ButtonStyle.Ok) {
        Button okButton = new Button {
            Width = 93,
            Height = 40,
            Location = new Point(x: 248, y: 202),
            Text = "OK"
        };
        okButton.Click += new EventHandler(OkButtonEventHandler);
    }
    return _result;
}

private static void OkButtonEventHandler(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    _result = DialogResult.OK;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You don't even need to handle click events. All you need is to set the [Button.DialogResult Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.button.dialogresult(v=vs.110).aspx) of the buttons you create as stated in the documentation

> **Remarks**
>
> If the *DialogResult* for this property is set to anything other than **None**, and if the parent form was displayed through the *ShowDialog* method, clicking the button closes the parent form without your having to hook up any events. The form's *DialogResult* property is then set to the *DialogResult* of the button when the button is clicked.
>   For example, to create a "Yes/No/Cancel" dialog box, simply add three buttons and set their *DialogResult* properties to **Yes**, **No**, and **Cancel**.

I think it's self explanatory, but just in case, here is the modified version of  your sample code

```
public static DialogResult Show(string title, string message, ButtonStyle buttonStyle) {
    AFGMessageBox box = new AFGMessageBox();
    box.Text = title;
    box.LblMessage.Text = message;
    if (buttonStyle == ButtonStyle.Ok) {
        Button okButton = new Button {
            Width = 93,
            Height = 40,
            Location = new Point(x: 248, y: 202),
            Text = "OK",
            DialogResult = DialogResult.OK
        };
        box.Controls.Add(okButton);
    }
    return box.ShowDialog();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your method `AFGMessageBox.Show` as follows:

```
public static DialogResult Show(string title, string message, ButtonStyle buttonStyle) {
    AFGMessageBox box = new AFGMessageBox();
    box.Text = title;
    box.LblMessage.Text = message;
    if(buttonStyle == ButtonStyle.Ok) {
        Button okButton = new Button {
            Width = 93,
            Height = 40,
            Location = new Point(x: 248, y: 202),
            Text = "OK"
        };
        box.Controls.Add(okButton); // add the button to your dialog!
        okButton.Click += (s, e) => { // add click event handler as a closure
            box.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK; // set the predefined result variable
            box.Close(); // close the dialog
        };
    }
    return box.ShowDialog(); // display the dialog! (it returns box.DialogResult by default)
}
```